# Rails associations routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have two models `Blog` and `User` with the following association

```
Blog belongs_to :user
```

My routes are as follows

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
  resources :blogs
end
```

These are the routes generated

```
   user_blogs GET    /users/:user_id/blogs(.:format)     blogs#index
              POST   /users/:user_id/blogs(.:format)     blogs#create
new_user_blog GET    /users/:user_id/blogs/new(.:format) blogs#new
    edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)           blogs#edit
         blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)                blogs#show
```

The question is why some routes ( `new_user_blog` for example) have the right routing, but others (`edit_blog` should be `edit_user_blog`) are wrong?

Comment: Do you also have `resources :blogs` outside of the nested `:users` resources?

Comment: It's because you have requested shallow routing, it's not wrong.  That is what happens with shallow routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting these routes because of [**`shallow-nesting`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting)

shallow nesting only generates nested routes for **`index`**, **`create`** and **`new`**

As per the documentation using shallow option is equivalent to generate routes as below:

```
resources :users do
  resources :blogs, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
resources :blogs, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Which will generate

```
    user_blogs  GET    /users/:user_id/blogs(.:format)      blogs#index
                POST   /users/:user_id/blogs(.:format)      blogs#create
 new_user_blog  GET    /users/:user_id/blogs/new(.:format)  blogs#new
     edit_blog  GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)            blogs#edit
          blog  GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)                 blogs#show
                PATCH  /blogs/:id(.:format)                 blogs#update
                PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)                 blogs#update
                DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)                 blogs#destroy
         users  GET    /users(.:format)                     users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)                     users#create
      new_user  GET    /users/new(.:format)                 users#new
     edit_user  GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)            users#edit
          user  GET    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#show
                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                 users#destroy
```

whereas using `shallow` option generates exact same routes as above